# Cannot echo JSON containing array of object - PHP

Tags: php, json

I am trying to echo `json_encode` an associative array that contains an array of objects.  The output is always blank.  My code is below.  Please can someone advise?

```
$repeatSerialNumArray = array();
// Total number of records inserted
$totalRecordsInserted = 0;
```

The following is in a while loop:

```
 $dsRecordObject = new dsRecord($SerialNumber, $MAC_Address);
 array_push($repeatSerialNumArray, $dsRecordObject);
```

I then echo the resultant array of objects:

```
 $output['repeatObjects'] = $repeatSerialNumArray;
 $output['records_inserted'] = $totalRecordsInserted;
 $output['message'] = 'fileUploadedRead';
 echo json_encode($output);
```

I know that if I eliminate `$output['repeatObjects'] = $repeatSerialNumArray;` from the above, I do get a JSON output.

```
 class dsRecord{

public $SerialNumber;
public $MAC_Address;


public function __construct($SerialNumber, $MAC_Address){

    $this -> SerialNumber = $SerialNumber;
    $this -> MAC_Address = $MAC_Address;
}

}
```

Comment: what does `print_r($repeatSerialNumArray)` returns?

Comment: its prints out the array of objects correctly

Comment: Do your objects contain public properties that cannot be encoded, like resources?

Comment: Can you try utf8_encode() on this variable before json_encode()?

Comment: @jeroen please see update above

Comment: Do you read the error_log?

Comment: What happens if you echo `json_last_error()`?

Comment: can you show the output becase most probably a value is violating json structure roles. add the output of this to the question : print_r($repeatSerialNumArray)

Comment: @ChiragAggarwal If you want to put this down as an answer i can accept it.  It looks like one of the input variables I used to create the object needed UTF-8 encoding!!.  thanks everyone for contributing.  Appreciate it!

Comment: also : Note: If you use array_push() to add one element to the array it's better to use $array[] = because in that way there is no overhead of calling a function.(from the docs)